# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression - Call a function in select

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by

I have a problem when call two functions in a SELECT.
In the main Select, call to functions "getCodGama" and "getDescGama".
When I try to run this, show the next error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".
If I put those two alias (codGama and descGama) on Group By, I have the same error.
I don´t know what can I do, because, If I put or don´t those two Alias of a function in the group by, I have the same error.
Function "getCodGama" return a VARCHAR2.
Function "getDescGama" return a VARCHAR2.

```
SELECT productos.prod_nmu                nmuproducto,
                marcas.marc_codmarca              codmarca,
                familias.fami_codfamilia          codfamilia,
                depositosfisicos.depf_coddeposito coddeposito,
                stock.stck_codstock               codstock,
                inventariopartidas.part_codpart   codpart,
                /*GAMA*/
                TO_CHAR(negozi.pkg_inv_mdw_servicios_ne.getCodGama(productos.fami_idfamilia)) codGama,
                TO_CHAR(negozi.pkg_inv_mdw_servicios_ne.getDescGama(productos.fami_idfamilia)) descGama,
                --
                SUM (exist.cantidadexist)         cantidadexist ,
                SUM (exist.cantidadexist - nvl(reservas.cantidadres,0) ) cantidaddisp

         FROM   n2_inv_expr_existencia_produc  existenciaproduc,
                n2_inv_prod_productos          productos,
                n2_inv_depf_deposito_fisico    depositosfisicos,
                n2_inv_estl_estructura_logica  estructlogica,
                n2_inv_depl_deposito_logico    deplogico,
                n2_inv_gcom_grupos_comerciales gruposcomerciales,
                n2_inv_fami_familias           familias,
                n2_inv_stck_stocks             stock,
                n2_inv_rstp_rela_stock_partida relastockpartida,
                n2_inv_part_partidas           inventariopartidas,
                n2_inv_tdep_tipo_deposito      tipodedeposito,
                N2_INV_MARC_MARCAS             marcas,
                /*Gama*/
                --n2_ate_para_parametros para,-- retorna descripcion de gama en cursor
                --n2_cco_sgfa_subgamas_familias sgfa,
                --n2_ate_sgam_subgamas sgam,
                --
                /* Existencias */
    ( SELECT existenciaproduc.expr_idexistencia, relastockpartida.rstp_idrelstpart,-- sgfa.fami_idfamilia, sgam.sgam_gama_id,
                     COUNT(distinct existenciaserial.exsr_esn_pin ) cantidadexist
         FROM   n2_inv_expr_existencia_produc existenciaproduc,
                n2_inv_exsr_existencias_serial existenciaserial,
                n2_inv_prod_productos         productos,
                n2_inv_depf_deposito_fisico   depositosfisicos,
                n2_inv_estl_estructura_logica estructlogica,
                n2_inv_depl_deposito_logico   deplogico,
                n2_inv_gcom_grupos_comerciales gruposcomerciales,
                n2_inv_fami_familias          familias,
                n2_inv_stck_stocks            stock,
                n2_inv_rstp_rela_stock_partida relastockpartida,
                n2_inv_part_partidas          inventariopartidas,
                n2_inv_tdep_tipo_deposito     tipodedeposito,
                N2_INV_MARC_MARCAS            marcas,
                /*Gama*/
                n2_ate_para_parametros para,
                n2_cco_sgfa_subgamas_familias sgfa,
                n2_ate_sgam_subgamas sgam
          WHERE productos.prod_idproducto       = existenciaproduc.prod_idproducto
          AND   existenciaserial.expr_idexistencia =existenciaproduc.expr_idexistencia
          AND   depositosfisicos.depf_iddeposito= existenciaproduc.depf_iddeposito
          AND   depositosfisicos.tdep_idtipo    = tipodedeposito.tdep_idtipo
          AND   existenciaproduc.estl_idestruct_logica = estructlogica.estl_idestruct_logica
          AND   estructlogica.rstp_idrelstpart  = relastockpartida.rstp_idrelstpart
          AND   stock.stck_idstock              = relastockpartida.stck_idstock
          AND   inventariopartidas.part_idpartida = relastockpartida.part_idpartida
          AND   depositosfisicos.tdep_idtipo    = estructlogica.tdep_idtipo
          AND   estructlogica.depl_idlogico     = deplogico.depl_idlogico
          AND   productos.gcom_idgrupocom       = gruposcomerciales.gcom_idgrupocom
          AND   productos.marc_idmarca          = marcas.marc_idmarca
         -- AND   gruposcomerciales.gcom_producto_servicio = ctegrpPortable
          AND   productos.fami_idfamilia        = familias.fami_idfamilia(+)
          /*Gama*/
          AND  para.para_valor2 = sgam.sgam_gama_id
          AND  para.para_atributo = 'GAMAS TERMINALES'
          AND  sgfa.sgfa_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND  sgam.sgam_activo = 'S'
          AND  sgfa.sgam_idsubgama = sgam.sgam_idsubgama
          AND  sgfa.fami_idfamilia = productos.fami_idfamilia
          --
          AND   depositosfisicos.depf_iddeposito= 688--idep
          AND   stock.stck_disponible           = 'S'
          --AND  ( productos.prod_idproducto      = idproducto   OR idproducto = -1 )
          AND  ( stock.stck_codstock            = nvl(NULL,   stock.stck_codstock)  )--nvl(codStock,   stock.stck_codstock)  )
          AND  ( marcas.marc_codmarca           = nvl(NULL,   marcas.marc_codmarca )  )--nvl(codMarca,   marcas.marc_codmarca )  )
          AND  ( familias.fami_codfamilia       = nvl(NULL, familias.fami_codfamilia))--nvl(codFamilia, familias.fami_codfamilia))
          AND  (para.para_valor2                = nvl(NULL, para.para_valor2))--nvl(pcodGama, para.para_valor2))
          GROUP BY existenciaproduc.expr_idexistencia, relastockpartida.rstp_idrelstpart)--, sgfa.fami_idfamilia, sgam.sgam_gama_id)
          exist,
            /* Reservas */
        (SELECT   expr_idexistencia, RSTP_IDRELSTPART, SUM (repm_cant_reservada) cantidadres
         FROM     n2_inv_repm_reservaprod_mdw
         GROUP BY expr_idexistencia, RSTP_IDRELSTPART) reservas

          WHERE productos.prod_idproducto       = existenciaproduc.prod_idproducto
          AND   depositosfisicos.depf_iddeposito= existenciaproduc.depf_iddeposito
          AND   depositosfisicos.tdep_idtipo    = tipodedeposito.tdep_idtipo
          AND   existenciaproduc.estl_idestruct_logica = estructlogica.estl_idestruct_logica
          AND   estructlogica.rstp_idrelstpart = relastockpartida.rstp_idrelstpart
          AND   stock.stck_idstock             = relastockpartida.stck_idstock
          AND   inventariopartidas.part_idpartida = relastockpartida.part_idpartida
          AND   depositosfisicos.tdep_idtipo   = estructlogica.tdep_idtipo
          AND   estructlogica.depl_idlogico    = deplogico.depl_idlogico
          AND   productos.gcom_idgrupocom      = gruposcomerciales.gcom_idgrupocom
          AND   productos.marc_idmarca         = marcas.marc_idmarca
          -- Contabilizamos existencias
          AND   existenciaproduc.expr_idexistencia = exist.expr_idexistencia
          AND   relastockpartida.rstp_idrelstpart =  exist.rstp_idrelstpart
          /*Gama*/
          --AND   productos.fami_idfamilia = exist.fami_idfamilia
          --AND   para.para_valor2         = exist.sgam_gama_id
          --AND   para.para_atributo       = 'GAMAS TERMINALES'
          -- Contabilizo reservas
          AND   exist.expr_idexistencia = reservas.expr_idexistencia(+)
          AND   exist.rstp_idrelstpart  = reservas.RSTP_IDRELSTPART(+)
          AND   productos.fami_idfamilia= familias.fami_idfamilia(+)
          --AND  sgfa.sgfa_fecha_baja IS NULL
          --AND  sgam.sgam_activo = 'S'
          --AND  sgfa.sgam_idsubgama = sgam.sgam_idsubgama

          --AND  (pcodGama IS NULL OR para.para_valor2 = pcodGama)
          --
          GROUP BY productos.prod_nmu,
                   marcas.marc_codmarca,
                   familias.fami_codfamilia,
                   depositosfisicos.depf_coddeposito,
                   stock.stck_codstock,
                   inventariopartidas.part_codpart;
```

Comment: You need to repeat the entire function call in the GROUP BY, not just the alias. Also be aware that embedding row-level function calls like that will have a _serious_ impact on performance if your data set is more than a few rows. For something this complex you may want to consider using a materialized view to collect the results periodically and then do adhoc queries against the MV.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example might make the issue clearer. If your query is like this:

```
select max(upper(dummy)) as demo
from   dual d
group by d.demo;

ORA-00904: "D"."DEMO": invalid identifier
```

then it needs to be like this:

```
select max(upper(dummy)) as demo
from   dual d
group by upper(dummy);
```

From a performance perspective, make sure your user-defined functions are defined as deterministic (assuming they actually are, which I'm guessing they must be or they wouldn't be much use in SQL queries) to ensure that they are called as few times as possible, and for good measure parallel-enabled in case you want to use them in a parallel query.

Answer (score 0):

You may only need to include productos.fami_idfamilia in your group by clause. If a function uses a field from the query and that query is grouping it needs to be included